# How to set cell value in excel using apache poi

Tags: excel, apache-poi

i am trying to setCell value like here:

```
Cell cell = getCell(sheet, cellAddress);
cell.setCellValue("test3");
```

and this is working.
The issue is that i have already background color defined in workbook and do not want to loose it.

I tried to:

```
        Cell cell = getCell(sheet, cellAddress);
        CellStyle style = cell.getCellStyle();
        cell.setCellValue("test3");
        cell.setCellStyle(style);
```

But this is removing green background and keeping only set up text.

Please help,
Michal

Comment: Where does the `getCell` method come from? That doesn't look like a built-in Apache POI function with those arguments

Comment: this is mine method
 private Cell getCell(XSSFSheet wsh, String cellRefer){
  CellReference cellReference = new CellReference(cellRefer);
  int nRow = cellReference.getRow();
  int nCol = cellReference.getCol();

  XSSFRow sheetrow;
  XSSFCell cell = null;
  if (wsh.getLastRowNum() == -1) {
   sheetrow = wsh.createRow(nRow);
   cell = sheetrow.createCell(nCol);
  } else {
   sheetrow = wsh.getRow(nRow);
   if (sheetrow == null ) {
    sheetrow = wsh.createRow(nRow);
    cell = sheetrow.createCell(nCol);
   } else if (cell == null) {
  cell = sheetrow.createCell(nCol);
  (...)

Comment: All relevant code must be part of the question. Comments are not to provide code as code is not readable in comments.

Comment: Don't call `createCell` - it will create a new blank cell

Comment: @Gagravarr thanks. oo let me check this. So instead of creating cell i should getCell instead? How to do this?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/components/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator

Answer (score 1):

You can take reference from my code :

```
public class ExcelGenerator {
    public static String taskToExcel(List<TaskEntity> taskEntities) throws IOException {
        String[] columns = {
                "taskId",
                "taskType",
                "taskName",
                "taskDescription",
                "taskPriority",
                "taskStatus",
                "loggedHours",
                "estimatedTimeInDays",
                "remainingTimeInDays",
                "taskLabel",
                "startDate",
                "endDate"
        };

        try (Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
             ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
            Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("Tasks");
            Row headerRow = sheet.createRow(0);
            for (int col = 0; col < columns.length; col++) {
                Cell cell = headerRow.createCell(col);
                cell.setCellValue(columns[col]);
            }
            int rowIndex = 1;
            for (TaskEntity task : taskEntities) {
                Row row = sheet.createRow(rowIndex++);
                row.createCell(0).setCellValue(task.getTaskId());
                row.createCell(1).setCellValue(task.getTaskType());
                row.createCell(2).setCellValue(task.getTaskName());
                row.createCell(3).setCellValue(task.getTaskDescription());
                row.createCell(4).setCellValue(task.getTaskPriority());
                row.createCell(5).setCellValue(task.getTaskStatus());
                row.createCell(6).setCellValue(task.getLoggedHours());
                row.createCell(7).setCellValue(task.getEstimatedTimeInDays());
                row.createCell(8).setCellValue(task.getRemainingTimeInDays());
                row.createCell(9).setCellValue(task.getTaskLabel());
                row.createCell(10).setCellValue(String.valueOf(task.getStartDate()));
                row.createCell(11).setCellValue(String.valueOf(task.getEndDate()));
            }
            workbook.write(outputStream);
            String filename = "D://excel/" + "task.xls";
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(filename);
            fileOutputStream.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
            return "Excel exported successfully";
        }
    }
}
```